# Spring Cloud Stream - Send message synchronously with wait time

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, stream, spring-kafka, synchronous

i am using Spring stream @StreamListener to send message synchronously where the consumer will hit the Rest end point and the message will be posted to Kafka.

I can able to achieve the sync by using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.sync=true but when the Kafka is down, the Timeout Exception not occurring so the consumer waiting for ~2 min.
i tried to set max.block.ms as well but it didn't work for me. Below is the configuration.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.sync=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.configuration.max.block.ms=5000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.test.type=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.binders.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.binders.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.binders.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=test
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.group=testgroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=topic1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.producer.header-mode=headers
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration properties, including how you are setting `max.block.ms`. Edit the question, and comment that you have done so, don't put the properties in a comment.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your response. Added the configuration property in question.

Comment: Try setting it on the `output` binding (instead of `default`). What version are you using? The `zkNodes` property was removed a long time ago (and was deprecated before that). Modern Kafka client versions don't talk directly to Zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have removed zookeeper configuration now. I am using spring version Hoxton.SR11 which using spring-messaging 5.2.14.RELEASE.jar. I added the configuraiton in output channel but it didn't work for me. Below is the configuration added after removing this from default group.

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.configuration.max.block.ms=5000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.sync=true

Comment: Its works when i remove max.block.ms and adding below configuraton.

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.configuration.request.timeout.ms=5000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.configuration.delivery.timeout.ms=5000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.test.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.requiredAcks=-1

Comment: @GaryRussell The only issue that i have right now is that even when the TimeoutException occurs, i am seeing that message is sent to Kafka. Is there is any way to block it when timeout occurs ?